# Determine ports used for connections on a node from netflow data

Tags: tcp, network-programming, udp, port, netflow

Given NetFlow data I would like to infer as much port information about the nodes as possible. Such as what ports are closed, what ports are being used for connections, and what ports are open. How can this be done? I think it is ok to assume my netflow data comes with TCP flag information.